# Changing color of progress bar when it reaches 100%

Tags: javascript, html, progress

I have a rounded progress bar that goes for a minute, and starts over.
Right now, the background is grey and the progress bar is blue. I need when it reaches 100%, everything is blue, and then when it starts over, the blue stays as a background and the progress bar becomes grey. When it reaches 100%, same thing over again, background is gray and progress bar is blue. Everytime it starts, color changes.
Here is my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/BrsJsk/gdLu77dc/

```
div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #c8c9cb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.counter {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
}

div > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.quad1,
.quad4 {
  top: 0%;
}

.quad2,
.quad3 {
  top: 50%;
}

.quad1,
.quad3 {
  transform: skew(0deg);
  /* invisible at -90deg */
}

.quad2,
.quad4 {
  transform: skewY(0deg);
  /* invisible at 90deg */
}


/* Just for demo */

div[data-progress] {
  margin: 40px auto;
}

<div data-progress="0">
        <div class="quad1"></div>
        <div class="quad2"></div>
        <div class="quad3"></div>
        <div class="quad4"></div>
        <div class='counter'></div>
      </div>

{
      var progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
        quad1 = document.querySelector('.quad1'),
        quad2 = document.querySelector('.quad2'),
        quad3 = document.querySelector('.quad3'),
        quad4 = document.querySelector('.quad4'),
        counter = document.querySelector('.counter');


      var progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 600);

      function incrementProg() {
        progress = parseInt(progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress'));
        progress = ((progress + 1) % 100);
        if (progress === 0) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
          quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
          quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
        }
        progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', progress); //set value to attribute
        counter.textContent = 100 - parseInt(progress, 10); // set countdown timer's value
        setPie(progress); // call the paint progress bar function based on progress value
      }

      function setPie(progress) {
        /* If progress is less than 25, modify skew angle the first quadrant */
        if (progress <= 25) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + progress * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
          progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');

        }

        /* Between 25-50, hide 1st quadrant + modify skew angle of 2nd quadrant */
        else if (progress > 25 && progress <= 50) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 25) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
          progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
        }

        /* Between 50-75, hide first 2 quadrants + modify skew angle of 3rd quadrant */
        else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 75) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
          quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + (progress - 50) * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
          progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
        }

        /* Similar to above for value between 75-100 */
        else if (progress > 75 && progress < 100) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
          quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 3rd completely
          quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 75) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
          progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
        }
      }
    }
```

And here is the code for changing colors but its not working.

```
var barFull = 0;
      if (barFull = 1) {
        progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #c8c9cb');
         quad1.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2'); 
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2'); 
          quad3.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
          quad4.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
      }
      else {
        progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
         quad1.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #c8c9cb'); 
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #c8c9cb'); 
          quad3.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #c8c9cb'); 
          quad4.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #c8c9cb');
      }
      if (progress == 100) {
        barFull = 1;
      }  
      else {
        barFull = 0;
      }
```

Comment: `if(barFull=1)` is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just modify CSS for progresbar and add one more rule for alternate state:

```css
div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #c8c9cb;
  color: #6edbf2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div[data-progress].alternate {
  background: #6edbf2;
  color: #c8c9cb;
}
```

Then in JS you need to toggle this `.alternate` class:

```
if (progress === 0) {
    progressbar.classList.toggle('alternate')
    // ...
}
```

Check the demo below (I made it progress faster for the demo):

```js
{
  var progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
    quad1 = document.querySelector('.quad1'),
    quad2 = document.querySelector('.quad2'),
    quad3 = document.querySelector('.quad3'),
    quad4 = document.querySelector('.quad4'),
    counter = document.querySelector('.counter');

  var progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 30);

  function incrementProg() {
    progress = parseInt(progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress'));
    progress = (progress + 1) % 100;

    if (progress === 0) {
     progressbar.classList.toggle('alternate')
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
      quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
    }
    progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', progress); //set value to attribute
    counter.textContent = 100 - parseInt(progress, 10); // set countdown timer's value
    setPie(progress); // call the paint progress bar function based on progress value
  }

  function setPie(progress) {
    /* If progress is less than 25, modify skew angle the first quadrant */
    if (progress <= 25) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + progress * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px');
    }

    /* Between 25-50, hide 1st quadrant + modify skew angle of 2nd quadrant */
    else if (progress > 25 && progress <= 50) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 25) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px');
    }

    /* Between 50-75, hide first 2 quadrants + modify skew angle of 3rd quadrant */
    else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 75) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + (progress - 50) * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px');
    }

    /* Similar to above for value between 75-100 */
    else if (progress > 75 && progress < 100) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 3rd completely
      quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 75) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #c8c9cb;
  color: #6edbf2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div[data-progress].alternate {
  background: #6edbf2;
  color: #c8c9cb;
}


.counter {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
  color: #000;
}

div > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.quad1,
.quad4 {
  top: 0%;
}

.quad2,
.quad3 {
  top: 50%;
}

.quad1,
.quad3 {
  transform: skew(0deg);
  /* invisible at -90deg */
}

.quad2,
.quad4 {
  transform: skewY(0deg);
  /* invisible at 90deg */
}


/* Just for demo */

div[data-progress] {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<div data-progress="0">
  <div class="quad1"></div>
  <div class="quad2"></div>
  <div class="quad3"></div>
  <div class="quad4"></div>
  <div class='counter'></div>
</div>
```

Few notes. I removed color information for box-shadow from JS and made use of color property for progresbar instead as `box-shadow` uses `color` prop as default color if not provided. This allows us to change `box-shadow` toggling CSS class without polluting JS code.